# Ошибочное масштабирование SVG в Safari

Tags: ios, svg, mac, safari, масштабирование

Ох и проблемная эта тема `Safari` и `iOS` в принципе... вот проблема с отображением `svg`, а именно масштабированием. В браузерах типа `Yandex` и `Firefox` - все в порядке,

[image: приближение в яндекс браузере]

но как только начинаешь приближать в сафари... начинается мистика

[image: приближение на safari]

пробовал уже всякое... решения так и нет. Есть у кого идеи? может кто нибудь подсказать?

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin none" version="1.1" id="aicberg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="200 250 830 650" style="enable-background:new 700 0 430 750;" xml:space="preserve" width="100%" height="100%" baseProfile="full">

</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="552.2" cy="542" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221015" class="st8" cx="552.2" cy="542" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="15" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0.1811 0.9835 -0.9835 0.1811 551.0925 540.2667)" class="st2 st9">15</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="553.4" cy="548.4" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221014" class="st8" cx="553.4" cy="548.4" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="14" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0.1811 0.9835 -0.9835 0.1811 552.2682 546.6535)" class="st2 st9">14</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="554.6" cy="554.8" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221013" class="st8" cx="554.6" cy="554.8" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="13" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0.1811 0.9835 -0.9835 0.1811 553.5182 553.4417)" class="st2 st9">13</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="555.8" cy="561.2" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221012" class="st8" cx="555.8" cy="561.2" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="12" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0.1811 0.9835 -0.9835 0.1811 554.697 559.8379)" class="st2 st9">12</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="556.9" cy="567.6" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221011" class="st8" cx="556.9" cy="567.6" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="11" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0.1811 0.9835 -0.9835 0.1811 555.8972 566.3563)" class="st2 st9">11</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="558.1" cy="574" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221010" class="st8" cx="558.1" cy="574" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="10" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0.1811 0.9835 -0.9835 0.1811 557.0748 572.7507)" class="st2 st9">10</text>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="551.6" cy="534.9" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221016" class="st8" cx="551.6" cy="534.9" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="16" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 550.7813 532.9084)" class="st2 st10">16</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="551.6" cy="508.7" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221020" class="st8" cx="551.6" cy="508.7" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="20" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 550.7813 507.2495)" class="st2 st10">20</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="551.6" cy="515.2" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221019" class="st8" cx="551.6" cy="515.2" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="19" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 550.7813 513.7524)" class="st2 st10">19</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="551.6" cy="521.9" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221018" class="st8" cx="551.6" cy="521.9" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="18" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 550.7813 520.3813)" class="st2 st10">18</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="551.6" cy="489.2" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221023" class="st8" cx="551.6" cy="489.2" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="23" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 550.7813 487.7169)" class="st2 st10">23</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="551.6" cy="495.7" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221022" class="st8" cx="551.6" cy="495.7" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="22" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 550.7813 494.2198)" class="st2 st10">22</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="551.6" cy="476.4" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221025" class="st8" cx="551.6" cy="476.4" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="25" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 550.7813 474.8235)" class="st2 st10">25</text>
        </g>
        <g>
        <circle class="st7" cx="551.6" cy="482.9" r="3.1"></circle>
        <circle id="95221024" class="st8" cx="551.6" cy="482.9" r="2.6" data-row="10" data-seat="24" data-sector="Сектор undefined"></circle>
        <text transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 550.7813 481.3266)" class="st2 st10">24</text>
        </g>
        <g>
```

Все примерно в таком ключе. Я пробовал прописывать в css ширину и высоту #aicberg{width:2000px;height:1000px;}, на браузерах кроме `ios` и `safari` Отображение в порядке, но из за такого масштаба на сафари все плывет при приближении, просто даже цифр не разобрать -_- сейчас я удалил это css правило и оставил только viewbox, но разницы нету...

Для приближения использую `Zynga Scroller` возможно причина в нем?
Опробовал поставить плагин по приближению `iscroll`, тот же эффект...

Comment: Чтобы Вам возможно было оказать помощь, пожалуйста, дополните вопрос минимальным воспроизводимым примером Вашего SVG

Comment: @Rem без полного кода svg мы можем только посочувствовать вам. Если хотите получить ответ, то добавьте код в вопрос, а также обязательно добавьте код, как вы добавляете svg в HTML

Comment: я могу скинуть и больше кода, просто он весь практически повторяется

Comment: "начинается мистика"  - что именно вы имеете ввиду, что именно вы ожидаете получить, и что конкретно получаете вместо ожидаемого?

Comment: очень сильная размытость на сафари, вообще четкости нету, сейчас еще один скрин приложу, такого на яндекс браузере, хроме или еще где , нету.

Comment: не могу добавить пока -_- не грузит, на 2 скриншоте уже очень слабо различимы номер выбранного места, при дальнейшем приближении там просто размытые квадраты, в то время как на других браузерах все в порядке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Господа, все оказалось гораздо проще, в браузере сафари нельзя использовать `transform scale`, точнее его можно использовать, но приближение будет размытым, поэтому его нужно заменить на `transform matrix`! В `zynga scroller`, в файле `render.js` я переписал строку для приближение контента с

`content.style[transformProperty] = 'translate3d(' + (-left) + 'px,' + (-top) + 'px,0) scale(' + zoom + ')';`

на

`$('#content').css('transform','matrix(' + zoom + ',0,0,' + zoom + ',' + (-left) + ',' + (-top) + ')')`

у меня стоит обертка див с ид content и после этого все заработало на ура! Всем спасибо!